# How to interpret simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions?

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to learn on my own about confidence intervals for multinomial proportions, and I stumbled upon several resources on the subject talking about various methods (e.g. Goodman, or Sison-Glaz) . Yet, the resources I found are mathematically dense, and without guidance I'm afraid I have a hard time understanding how to interpret exactly such confidence intervals (beyond the general idea that they show some degree of uncertainty around each estimate).

For the moment, the two "hypothesis" I have relative to their interpretation are the following (but I guess that I may be completely on the wrong track):

- given a confidence level of 95% (just an example), if we were to repeat the sampling procedure a lot of times, then the true proportions (all of them) would fall 95% of the time in the simultaneous confidence intervals. In other words, to take an example with a sample of 4 exclusive categories: if we have 4 categories, with 3 confidence intervals capturing correctly the 3 corresponding true proportions in the population, but with 1 confidence interval failing to capture its corresponding real proportion, the whole thing is considered a failure, and the simultaneous confidence intervals for this sample all (all 4 of them) go in the 5% we expected to fail.
- or, taking the example above, this is not considered a complete failure, but considered 3 successes and 1 failure.

Is one of these two interpretations correct? If not, what is the correct interpretation? Do different methods require different interpretations?

I'm not against mathematical notation or explanation, but some concrete/numerical examples would also certainly help me wrapping my head around it. I'm totally comfortable with explanations using code snippets (in R or other languages).

Thanks.